# How to Find Labels by Class Name to Skip the Validation in jQuery forms.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    forms:function(opt){
        if(opt===undefined)
            opt={}
        this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this),
                data=th.data('forms'),
                _={
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'#',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,

                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)

                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                                //_.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    },
                    submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=this
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            if(!data)
                (typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(_,opt):_).init.call(th),
                th.data({cScroll:_}),
                data=_
            else
                _=typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(data,opt):data
        })
        return this
    }
})
})(jQuery)
```

I want to skip the **state**  and **phone** validation and submit the form. I have removed the regx and now its not checking the **state** and **phone**, but it is showing that field is required.

Here is piece of HTML code:

```
 <label class="state">
                                <input type="text" name="state" value="Your Website">
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid website.</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="phone">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number">
                                <span class="error">*Enter a valid contact number...</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This is a required field.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
```

I have also tried to remove the span which shows that fields that are required, but after that it does not submit the form (the submit button isn't working).

After spend a lot of time I recognized that form.js is validating all **label** in the HTML, how can I skip **label** by name in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

just add the class "notrequired" to the field that's not required.

Message:
*Het bericht is te kort. *Dit is een verplicht veld.